# how to show contoured or morphologically changed image in opencv

Tags: python, image, opencv

```
img = cv2.imread("/Users/meenakshi/Desktop/lala.jpg")
img=cv2.resize(img,(1200,700))
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
binary = cv2.inRange(gray,65,255)
image,contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(binary.copy(),cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cnt = max(contours, key= lambda x: cv2.contourArea(x))
cv2.imshow("Radar", cnt)
cv2.waitKey(0)
epsilon = 0.0005*cv2.arcLength(cnt,True)
cnt = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt,epsilon,True)
M = cv2.moments(cnt)
cX = int(M["m10"]/M["m00"])
cY = int(M["m01"]/M["m00"])
cv2.circle(cnt,(cX,cY),7,(0,255,0),-1)
```

this is my code, I want to see the final contoured image with the moment circle but when i givve

```
cv2.imshow("Image", cnt)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

error is showing as

```
(-15:Bad number of channels) Source image must have 1, 3 or 4 channels in function 'cvConvertImage'
```

What should I do?

Comment: Print `cnt.shape` and see how many channels it has. Then work out why. Another option is to put back all the `import` statements and missing code and share your image so folk can assist you.

Answer (score 0):

> `cv2.circle(cnt,(cX,cY),7,(0,255,0),-1)`

create a circle on contour with the max area. 
If you want to see a circle on the original image you can pass img instead of cnt

```
cv2.circle(img,(cX,cY),7,(0,255,0),-1)
cv2.imshow("Image", img)
```